# Unable to insert data through CommandLineRunner - Sprint Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an application where data that I am trying to insert at runtime using `CommandLineRunner` doesn't go through, whereas the table has been created.

I came across a post mentioning that I need to add `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation on the class implementing the `CommandLineRunner`.

It is worth mentioning that I am not having any error at runtime.

User.java (Entity)

```
@Data
@AllArgConstructor
@NoArgConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
    @NotNull
    private Integer age;
    @NotNull
    private String country;
}
```

UserService.java

```
@Service
public interface UserService {

public List<User> findAll();

public Optional<User> findById(Long id); 

public void add(User user);

public Optional<User> update(User user);

public Optional<User> delete(Long id);
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    

    @Override
    public void add(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
}
```

UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<?> add(@Valid @RequestBody User user){
        userService.add(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

LoadUserInDB.java

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Transactional
@Component
public class LoadUserInDB implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired 
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    
        User user = new User("John", "Doe", 30, "US");
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Console log

```
 2021-07-23 19:58:56.537[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m17676[0;39m 
 [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m 
 [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
 HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
 Hibernate: drop table if exists users CASCADE 
 Hibernate: create table users (id bigint generated by default as 
 identity, age integer, country varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), 
 last_name varchar(255), primary key (id))
[2m2021-07-23 19:58:56.955[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m17676[0;39m 
[2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m 
[36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: 
  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
 [2m2021-07-23 19:58:56.962[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m17676[0;39m 
[2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m 
[36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2021-07-23 19:58:57.166[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m17676[0;39m 
[2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m 
[36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database 
queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure 
spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
[2m2021-07-23 19:58:57.411[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m17676[0;39m 
[2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m 
[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat 
started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2021-07-23 19:58:57.418[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m17676[0;39m 
[2m- --[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.demo.Main                           
  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started Main in 2.453 seconds (JVM running for 
 2.957)
```

Comment: YOu don't need `@EnableJpaRepositores`. Assuming you have a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` it should be detected **if** you followed the best practices. Which we don't know as you left out all the packages from your classes. And please remove `@Repository` from the interface (it hurts my eyes and doesn't add anything).

Answer (score 0):

The `CommandLineRunner` is an interface meant to be used by beans that intended to `run` (some piece of work: initialization, configuration, synchronization...) when injected in a *Spring* context.

Being only an implementation of the `CommandLineRunner` interface, *Spring* `Component`s won't do much by their own.

You are missing the bootstrapping part in your code to spin up the whole app altogether and have the your `LoadUserInDB#run` method run:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaReporsitories
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

> Note that the `EnableJpaReporsitories` should be declared on configuration components.

Comment: Either you have written it poorly or you don't understand the `CommandLineRunner` (or I assume too much about the questioner). But the `CommandLineRunner` instances are automatically detected by Spring Boot and executed.

Comment: @tmarwen: Nope, it doesn't, I post the console log also perhaps this will help you